# Post a message on product form mail thread in odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo-11

I want to post a custom message on the product form mail thread programmatically, i've inhereted the product.template module and here's my code

```
from odoo import models,fields,api

class product_sheet(models.Model):

_inherit = ['product.template']

fieldx = fields.Float()

@api.onchange('fieldx')
def post_msg(self):
    self.message_post(body="Write something here")
```

I don't want to use the track_visibility, I just need to write something in the thread programmatically, but I don't know how the message_post method works

what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. What is the error that you are getting? Could you post the traceback.

Also you could try doing this in the write method, like this:

```
@api.multi
def write (self, values):
   res = super(YOURCLASS,self).write(values)
   if 'fieldx' in values:
       self.message_post(body="Write something")
   return res
```

Comment: just realised the error I was getting wasn't from the message_post,my bad ^^',
it doesn't give any errors now but the message still doesn't log in the thread

Comment: when I tried using the write method I got this error :
  `File "/home/meyssa/odoo-dev/custom-addons/product_sheet/models/product.py", line 34, in write
    res = super(product_sheet,self).write()
TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'`

Comment: Hey @meyoushizuka, I forgot to put in the "values" argument in the write method super call. You might be missing vals in your argument, can you show me your code?

Comment: the write method is working now!! thank you so much!!